# How to get a value from a select in an angular2 component?

Tags: angular, select

I have ran into multiple solutions but did not find anything of interested from my point of view.

I have a component :

```xml
<select [(ngModel)]="languages" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  <option *ngFor="let language of languages">{{language.languageName}}</option>
</select>
```

I have typescript file:

```ts
 getCountries(): void{
     this.country.find({}).subscribe((data)=>{
     this.countries = data;
     console.log(data);}, err =>{  console.log(err);});
```

which renders the following json in the console:

[image]

I have no idea why I cannot select any value as I tested also with `[value]`.

Comment: Why ngModel refers to array with languages?

Comment: I did it for a table already but as I do not feel very confident with this I do not  know.

Comment: I did it for a table already but as I do not feel very confident with this I do not  know. What does it have to refer to ?

Comment: i suppressed ngModel and all works fine.

Comment: I definitely need to understand how things work together.

Comment: Working now. Thanks. Unfortunately I am getting ("error.json is not a function") error message. any idea ?

Comment: @PhilippeCorrèges seems nothing can work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a `name` attribute and remove `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`.

[Forms:](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

> Each input element has a `name` property that is required by Angular Forms to register the control with the form.

What you can't do is to bind a single property to a multiple value type variable. If you want to select multiple values you should use

```html
<select multiple name="selectedLanguages" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguages">
    <option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.languageCode">  
        {{language.languageName}}
    </option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind `language` to `ngValue`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="languages" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  <option *ngFor="let language of languages" [ngValue]="language">{{language.languageName}}</option>
</select>
```